# Auto refreshing the content without reloading page, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page which shows the contents of a table. 
While the user views a page the contents of the table changes on a second-by-second basis. 
So the user has to refresh the page every time to see fresh and updated contents.
 How can i update contents of the jsp page without having to refresh the page.

here is my code pls

it will not work .Please give me your suggestions and if not give a sample code thanks

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <Title>Just A Test</Title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#load_me').load('samp.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
               //every 10000 milliseconds(10sec)
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="load_me"> <%@ include file="samp.jsp" %></div>
</body>
/html>
```

Comment: have you checked fiddler (or comparable tool) to see what `samp.jsp` is returning?

Comment: Is the above code working in jsp. is possible pls give me to edit that code

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var reloadData = 0; // store timer

                // load data on page load, which sets timeout to reload again
                loadData();
            });

            function loadData() {
                $('#load_me').load('samp.jsp', function() {
                    if (reloadData != 0)
                        window.clearTimeout(reloadData);
                    reloadData = window.setTimeout(loadData, 10000)
                }).fadeIn("slow"); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="load_me"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `refresh` will work but this will violate time out policy

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me, just try it and let me know if it works for you too.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <Title>Just A Test</Title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        $('#load_me').load('samp.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 1000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
                   //every 1000 milliseconds(1sec)
        </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div id="load_me"> <%@ include file="samp.jsp" %></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice, but explain it a bit more to  user2493093

Answer (score -1):

to load the contents without refresh the page you can use JQuery Ajax 
for more http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: `load` is a pass-through to `ajax`, which he is already using.

Comment: Is the above code working in jsp. is possible  pls give me to edit that code

Comment: what about jQuery get function instead of load?